# How to determine the process memory limit in Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, process, out-of-memory

I have been scouring the internet to find out how much memory a java process can take on a linux (red-hat) machine.  ( I am not talking about heap; rather, the entire amount of memory taken up by the java **Process**)

I don't have permission to execute anything on that machine. So I can't simply execute a program that consumes memory until Out-Of-Memory condition.

However, I do have permission to check config files, etc.  ( for example:  I tried to execute cat /proc/meminfo, but I can't understand it; it appears that none of its results stand for the parameter I want to know about).

I have tried out a java program on a separate red hat machine - on which I do have permission to execute programs -  and I was able to see java program grow up to around 3GB.

Is there some way I can find out how much memory a process can get ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ulimit is your friend. Java processes are no different than any others. But if you can't even run ulimit -a, it's hard to answer your question.

Comment: I executed "ulimit -a"  but what I got was output with a bunch of options to try out. So I tried "ulimit -m",  the result I got was "unimited"  .  I don't know what that means, but I don't think it means that a process can take unlimited memory.. does it ?

Comment: @rk2010 means there is no quota on memory usage by any process, the only hard limit is how much RAM and swap memory the computer has.

Comment: @Matias but there seems to be so much info (vague) on the internet stating that a certain process cannot consume more than 3GB of memory. What is your opinion of that?

Comment: @rk2010 That depends on whatever the OS is 64-bit or 32-bit, for 32-bit OS you can only address about 3.5 GB of memory per process. Anyway, if you have more memory than that, a 64-bit OS is "required".

Comment: The total memory a 32-bit process can have is unlimited (size of all storage on machine (hard-disks, ram etc) mines what is used else where. But the maximum that can be mapped (be accessed as direct addressable memory) at any one time is 4GB-(2 power n), n is often 30, giving 4GB-1GB=3GB. n of 29 will give you 3.5GB. I can not remember how to change n.

Comment: It should be noted that the `ulimit` command is a built-in to the `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash` shells. If you are spawning your process directly (without using a shell), this command does not exist.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a useful read: [Limiting time and memory consumption of a program in Linux](http://coldattic.info/shvedsky/pro/blogs/a-foo-walks-into-a-bar/posts/40), which lead to the [timeout](https://github.com/pshved/timeout) tool, which lets you cage a process (and it's forks) by time or memory consumption.

Answer (score 2):

I have been dealing with this exact problem and have found the best solution if you are using 2.6.24 or higher is to use cgroup / [cgroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups). An example would be like this, here is the default /etc/cgconfig.conf file with an added control group at the bottom. This control group limits the amout of physical memory to 100MB and the total virtual memory allocation to 200MB.

```
mount {
    cpuset  = /cgroup/cpuset;
    cpu = /cgroup/cpu;
    cpuacct = /cgroup/cpuacct;
    memory  = /cgroup/memory;
    devices = /cgroup/devices;
    freezer = /cgroup/freezer;
    net_cls = /cgroup/net_cls;
    blkio   = /cgroup/blkio;
}

group daemons/java_limited_process {
    memory {
        memory.limit_in_bytes = "104857600";
        memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes = "209715200";
    }
}
```

Once I have this configured, I can add process to the group like so

```
cgexec -g memory:daemons/java_limited_process /usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```

This will limit the memory of the main process and any children it spawns. It also has facilities to query memory usage in the controllers.