# Using fscanf() vs. fgets() and sscanf()

Tags: c

In the book Practical C Programming, I find that the combination of `fgets()` and `sscanf()` is used to read input. However, it appears to me that the same objective can be met more easily using just the `fscanf()` function:

From the book (the idea, not the example):

```
int main()
{
    int age, weight;
    printf("Enter age and weight: ");

    char line[20];
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    sscanf(line, "%d %d", &age, &weight);

    printf("\nYou entered: %d %d\n", age, weight);
    return 0;
}
```

How I think it should be:

```
int main()
{
    int age, weight;
    printf("Enter age and weight: ");
    fscanf(stdin, "%d %d", &age, &weight);

    printf("\nYou entered: %d %d\n", age, weight);
    return 0;
}
```

Or there is some hidden quirk I'm missing?

Comment: Can you post the code snippet from the book so we can see the differences?

Comment: Done. Please see. Both these programs produce identical output (at least to the eye).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are a few behavior differences in the two approaches. If you use `fgets()` + `sscanf()`, you must enter both values on the same line, whereas `fscanf()` on `stdin` (or equivalently, `scanf()`) will read them off different lines if it doesn't find the second value on the first line you entered.

But, probably the most important differences have to do with handling error cases and the mixing of line oriented input and field oriented input.

If you read a line that you're unable to parse with `sscanf()` after having read it using `fgets()` your program can simply discard the line and move on.  However, `fscanf()`, when it fails to convert fields, leaves all the input on the stream.  So, if you failed to read the input you wanted, you'd have to go and read all the data you want to ignore yourself.

The other subtle gotcha comes in if you want to mix field oriented (ala `scanf()`) with line oriented (e.g. `fgets()`) calls in your code.  When `scanf()` converts an `int` for example, it will leave behind a `\n` on the input stream (assuming there was one, like from pressing the enter key), which will cause a subsequent call to `fgets()` to return immediately with only that character in the input.  This is a really common issue for new programmers.

So, while you are right that you can just use `fscanf()` like that, you may be able to avoid some headaches by using `fgets()` + `sscanf()`.

Comment: This is true. On the other hand, you would add some headache because `fgets` would read a line with a maximum length which can cause trouble. Imagine your buffer is 10 chars (exaggerated just for example) and then given input: `"       12345\n"` which you would receive as `"       12"` and `"345\n"`. The most secure way is to use a loop over `fgets` and `realloc` to read a complete line no matter its size.

Comment: @Shahbaz I'm still new to C, but I tried this and found that "12345" doesn't get split up the way you explained ("12" and "345\n"). Instead, I got "12345" in the first variable and some negative garbage value in the second. What point were you trying to make? Why should this happen?

Comment: Shahbaz: for simple problems, choose a large enough buffer, read the first characters and ignore the others in a loop until you read a `'\n'` :)

Comment: @dotslash, with `fgets` you have to give a bounded buffer. If there is a number at the boundary of that size, it can get split. In your own example, try giving an input with 17 spaces followed by a 6 digit number.

Comment: @pmg, for simple problems, check for output of `scanf("%d", ...)` and if it's not 1, do `scanf("%*s")` and retry. For simple problems, it's easy. It's real problems that show how `fscanf` can be troublesome and as I point out `fgets` can get troublesome too.

Comment: @Shahbaz Do not agree about "read a complete line no matter its size.". Certainly a buffer should be of ample size - I prefer 2x typical max size.  But these days there are too many buffer attacks and thus allowing unlimited size is a way to crash a program.  Better to limit input length to a generous amount rather than unbounded.

Comment: @chux, sure you can generate a failure if a line started to get ridiculously large. What I'm saying is that if you want to keep a maximum size, which is fine, you'd then have to be sure the line you read has fit in the buffer, otherwise the data may not be reliable and you may need to ignore what part of the line you have already read as well as what part of it is still left. By the way, crashing a program by exhausting its memory is not really an attack. You can just [limit its memory](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4651234/912144), or send a KILL signal or whatever! It's not a security issue.

Comment: @Shahbaz You do raise some really interesting points! Thanks for this. :)

Answer (score 6):

The problem with only using `fscanf()` is, mostly, in error management.

Imagine you input "**51 years, 85 Kg**" to both programs.

The first program fails in the `sscanf()` and you still have the `line` to report errors to the user, to try a different parsing alternative, to *something*;

The second program fails at **years**, `age` is usable, `weight` is unusable.

**Remeber to always check the return value of `*scanf()` for error checking.**

```
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    if (sscanf(line, "%d%d", &age, &weight) != 2) /* error with input */;
```

Edit

With your first program, after the error, the input buffer is clear; with the second program the input buffer starts with YEAR...

Recovery in the first case is easy; recovery in the second case has to go through some sort of clearing the input buffer.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between `fscanf()` versus `fgets()`/`sscanf()` when:

1. Input data is well-formed.

> Two types of errors occur: I/O and format.  `fscanf()` simultaneously handles these two error types in one function but offers few recovery options.  The separate `fgets()` and `sscanf()` allow logical separation of I/O issues from format ones and thus better recovery.

2. Only 1 parsing path with `fscanf()`.

> Separating I/O from scanning as with `fgets/sscanf` allows multiple `sscanf()` options.  Should a given scanning of a buffer not realize the desired results, other `sscanf()` with different formats are available.

3. No embedded `'\0'`.

> Rarely does `'\0'` occurs, but should one occur, `sscanf()` will not see it as scanning stops with its occurrence, whereas `fscanf()` continues.

In all cases, check results of all three functions.