# Match two strings with = as separator in fscanf

Tags: c, scanf

My aim is to extract the value and a key separated by an `=`. My initial idea was to use something like `%s=%s`, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

So I have a file:

```
A=1
B=2
```

So I open the file:

```
char *key;
char *value;

FILE* file = fopen("./file", "r");
do {
  fscanf(file, "%[^'=']=%[^'\n']\n", key, value);
  printf("key:%s value:%s\n", key, value);
} while(!feof(file));
```

However both key and value return:

```
key:1 value:1
key:2 value:2
```

Any idea why my expression is not matching?.

Comment: You're using `%[` incorrectly

Answer (score 2):

`key` and `value` variables must be allocated, e.g.

```
char key[100];
char value[1000];
```

Then use them.

Answer (score 1):

```
char key[16];//char *key;//not point to memory for store.
char value[16];

FILE *file = fopen("./file", "r");
while(2==fscanf(file, " %[^=]=%[^\n]", key, value)){
  printf ("key:%s value:%s\n", key, value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pointers are uninitialized. Reading them is undefined in C. You can use arrays (if you know the maximal lengths at compile-time) or allocate memory with `malloc`.

Read the `*scanf` documentation carefully, these functions are a little tricky.

`"%s=%s"` cannot match, `%s` consumes all `=` signs so the following `=` is always a matching failure (the next character after `%s` is always a whitespace or EOF).

When reading strings, always use a maximum field width (in some cases, it can be omitted safely, but only for `sscanf`). Unfortunately, you have to hard-code that value (or build up the format string at run-time, but I wouldn’t advise you to do so).

I'm not sure what the `'` in the scan sets are supposed to do, `%[^'=']` is equivalent to `%[^'=]` and matches everything but `'` and `=`. You’ve probably meant `%[^=]`.

Every white-space character in the format string (outside a scan set) is treated equally as "skip any white-space", that is, a space () is the same as a newline. The whole format string is equivalent to

```
"%[^'=]=%[^'\n] " // Note the space at the end
```

To match a literal newline, you need to use a scanset (with a length).

Always check the return value of `*scanf` (also for `fopen` and any other function which can fail).

```
char key[64];   // Or whatever is appropriate for you,
char value[64]; // remember the 0-terminator needs one byte

FILE *file = fopen("./file", "r");
if(!file) {
    perror("./file");
    exit(1);
}
for(;;) {
    int e = fscanf(file, "%63[^=]=%63[^\n]%1[\n]", key, value, (char[2]){ 0 });
    if(e == -1) {
        if(ferror(file)) {
            perror("reading from ./file");
            // handle read error
        } else { // EOF reached on first character of line
            break;
        }
    } else if(e < 3) {
        // handle invalid input
    } else {
        printf("key:%s value:%s\n", key, value);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use assignment-suppression for the last newline as in `"%63[^=]=%63[^\n]%*1[\n]"` and omit the last argument to `fscanf`. By doing so, you can no longer detect if the last line ended in a newline.

Answer (score 0):

> My initial idea was to use something like `%s=%s`, but unfortunately it
>   doesn't work.

Thats simply because `*scanf` **does not** respect non-whitespace delimiters as you suspected. Furthermore, it does not support real regular expressions. Only a certain simple type of character classes `[..]` are supported.

To your problem:

`key`and `value`have to be allocated static or dynamic, the rest can be simplified and written without `fscanf` (your input is obviously line-oriented), which might get you [into trouble at some point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330969/using-fscanf-vs-fgets-and-sscanf):

```
  ...
  FILE* fh = fopen("file", "r");
  char buffer[1024]; /* line buffer for reading file if file is line-oriented */

  while( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fh) ) {
     char key[256], val[256];
     sscanf(buffer, "%[^=]=%[^\n]", key, val);
     printf("key:%s val:%s\n", key, val);
  } 
  fclose(fh);
  ...
```

Edit the length of the scan buffers (`key[256]`, `val[256]`) depending on your input.

Comment: For the sake of security do: `sscanf(buffer, "%255[^'=']=%255[^'\n']", key, val);` with `255` being one less then the buffers' sizes.

Comment: @alk Thanks for the hint! This way, you could in a simple way avoid  buffer overrun on unknown input.

Answer (score 0):

```
// sample working code
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    FILE* file = fopen("./file", "r");

    if(NULL == file) {
        printf("Failed to open file\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    do {
        char key[256];
        char value[256];
        fscanf(file, "%[^'=']=%[^'\n']\n", key, value);
        printf("key:%s value:%s\n", key, value);
    }while(!feof(file));

    fclose(file);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} // End of main()
```

Sample Output:

```
key:A value:1
key:B value:2
key:C value:3
```