# C - do/while loop and switch(int). Typing a char value causes inf. loop

Tags: c

Can someone enlighten how to make this work? So now i have a do/while loop with a switch inside. The switch is handled by a int choice and scanf is "%d". But if I write an char symbol different from number like a,b,c... it goes into infinity loop. Changing int to char and %d to %c works but if something wrong is entered the menu repeats x2 and it becomes messy. Sorry for bad english :)
With int:

```
int main() {
 int choice;
    do{
        menu();
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch(choice) {
        case 1:
            // 1-vo poduslovie
            ReadSave();
            break;
        case 2:
            // 2-ro poduslovie
            ShowResult();
            break;
        case 3:
            // 3-to poduslovie
            SavetoScreen();
            break;
        case 4:
            // 4-to poduslovie
            PrinttoScreen();
            break;
        case 5: // exit
            return 0;
        default:
            printf("Wrong choice.\n");
    }
}while(choice!=5);
```

With char:

```
int main() {
 char choice;
    do{
        menu();
        scanf("%c", &choice);
    switch(choice) {
        case '1':
            // 1-vo poduslovie
            ReadSave();
            break;
        case '2':
            // 2-ro poduslovie
            ShowResult();
            break;
        case '3':
            // 3-to poduslovie
            SavetoScreen();
            break;
        case '4':
            // 4-to poduslovie
            PrinttoScreen();
            break;
        case '5': // exit
            return 0;
        default:
            printf("Wrong choice.\n");
    }
}while(choice!='5');
```

Comment: Show  a sample input sequence for each case.

Comment: Also, fix your parens and indentation.

Comment: `scanf("%c", &choice);` ==> `scanf(" %c", &choice);` please note that extra space. `%c` format otherwise reads the *next character* while other formats filter out whitespace.

Comment: Better yet, use `fgets` and apply `sscanf` and *always* check its return value. What is the return value of `scanf` family? Read the man pages. Using `fgets` it is easier to dump the string and try again, than to try clearing the bad input which will otherwise continue to block the buffer.

Comment: You should always check the return value from `scanf` to make sure it read the number of items you expected and didn't fail or hit eof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `%d`, if you enter a non-integer, `scanf` ignores it and *does not remove it from the input buffer.*  Each time through the loop, the non-character is still there, so `scanf` ignores it, `choice` never changes, and the loop never exits.

**Edit** You can tell that this is happening by checking the return value from `scanf`.  If the return value is `1`, scanf matched the `%d` which is the single (`1`) item in your format string.  If the return value is `0`, `scanf` couldn't match the `%d`, e.g., because of character data being present.  I presume this is what is happening in your code.

How to clear input before the `scanf` is discussed in detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7898516/2877364).  However, as [@WeatherVane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142924/weather-vane) said in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41349376/c-do-while-loop-and-switchint-typing-a-char-value-causes-inf-loop#comment69900568_41349376), you are probably better off to use `fgets` to get a whole line, then use `sscanf` to extract the integer (if any) from the string you got.  See, e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22331404/2877364).

Sources:

- The [`scanf` manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) says:

  > Reading of characters stops ... when a nonmatching character is found

  Hence the non-number is left in the input stream, e.g., for a future `scanf` to try to match.
- The [`fgets` manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)

Comment: Okay thanks for the answers people :) Will see what to choose to fit my use. because I am a total beginner and maybe I will make it with fgets. Here is the full code(I have to change that too because I used scanf more than once. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5H_NO3oeuLZNjJ2bjdzcWJsNzQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @MESA Glad to hear it!  If you found my answer helpful, would you please hit the upward-pointing triangle to mark it as such?  --- Also, welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more information to help you participate most effectively on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -2):

I ended using this:

```
int choice;
 char string[20];
    do{
        menu();
        fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
        sscanf(string, "%d", &choice);
     switch(choice) { /*menu......*/}
```

The full code:(havent edited it there yet). https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5H_NO3oeuLZNjJ2bjdzcWJsNzQ/view

Comment: to use stackoverflow as everyone else does you should upvote the person who told you how to do this -- not post a new answer.  This is not form.  Please read the FAQ for more information on how SO works.

Comment: Your "solution" contains undefined behaviour. You *must* check return values of functions you call.

Comment: This is a code-only answer and does not explain why it solves the problem.  It has weaknesses in not checking the return value of `fgets()` and `sscanf()` before using `string` and `choice` in the next lines.

Comment: Sorry people :). Will read the rules and FAQ now on how to use stackoverflow.