# Poblem with printing strings to file in c. First line won't show any text

Tags: c, file-handling

I am currently learning how to write to txt file in c. I encountered a problem where the first column of text won't output the string it has been given.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE * fptr;

    //open file
    fptr = fopen("test.txt", "a");

    //entering how many lines will be used
    int columns;
    scanf("%d", &columns);

    //loop for writing in lines
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        char temp_text[10001];
        fgets (temp_text, 10000, stdin);

        //to remove the \n caused by fgets
        temp_text[strlen(temp_text) - 1] = '\0';

        //fprintf is compatible with placeholders
        fprintf (fptr, "data %d: %s\n", i, temp_text);

    }

    //closing file
    fclose (fptr);

    return 0;
}
```

The inputs are:

```
5
qw 
er
ty
ui
```

I expected it to ask for n (in this case 5) time/s, instead it always asks for one less. The txt file shows:

```
data 0: 
data 1: qw
data 2: er
data 3: ty
data 4: ui
```

A shown, it always skips putting the given string on the first line as well.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't mix `scanf()` with `fgets()`. (Use the latter.) Scanf has left a dangling LF in the input buffer... Your output is exactly what `fgets()` has loaded, beginning with a LF and nothing else. You could skip the '5' and just let `fgets()` read to the end of the file...

Comment: @picchiolu It is, but I find the answers to the one I've linked are more on point regarding the question at hand.

Comment: Actually, the answers to both are not too good. I'd like to refer to a good fgets/sscanf-based answer. Did you notice one?

Comment: @moooeeeep oh yes, no criticism implied in my comment. I was trying to show that the same issue had already surfaced a few times.

Comment: Maybe this would be a relevant link too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22330969/1025391

Answer (score 0):

In the code posted by the OP, immediately after the user enters the value for `columns`, the program enters the for loop and tries to read from stdin, which happens to be just a LF (line-feed). For the OP's code to work, the user would have to enter, say, `5 blabla` instead of just `5`, when requested for the number of columns, so that `fgets` has something to read after `scanf` has consumed the digits for `columns`.

As the problem is related to the way the code handles user's input, I altered the original code so that it doesn't open/write to a file and uses scanf instead of fgets in the loop, and I tested it on https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/online-compiler/. The following version works as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    //FILE * fptr;

    //open file
    //fptr = fopen("test.txt", "a");

    //entering how many lines will be used
    int columns;
    printf("Enter n of cols: ");
    scanf("%d", &columns);

    //loop for writing in lines
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        char temp_text[100];
        scanf ("%s", &temp_text);

        //to remove the \n caused by fgets
        //temp_text[strlen(temp_text) - 1] = '\0';

        //fprintf is compatible with placeholders
        printf ("entered for %d: %s\n", i, temp_text);

    }

    //closing file
    //fclose (fptr);

    return 0;
}
```