# Mallet: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError with 1024GB Memory allocation

Tags: java, lda, mallet

I am trying to use Mallet to run topic modeling on a ~1GB text file, with 11403956 rows. From the mallet directory, I `cd` to `bin` and upgrade the memory requirement to 1024GB:

`set MALLET_MEMORY=1024G`

I then try to run the command:

```
bin/mallet import-file --input combined_bios.txt --output dh_size.mallet --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords
```

However, this throws a memory error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at gnu.trove.TObjectIntHashMap.rehash(TObjectIntHashMap.java:170)
        at gnu.trove.THash.postInsertHook(THash.java:359)
        at gnu.trove.TObjectIntHashMap.put(TObjectIntHashMap.java:155)
        at cc.mallet.types.Alphabet.lookupIndex(Alphabet.java:115)
        at cc.mallet.types.Alphabet.lookupIndex(Alphabet.java:123)
        at cc.mallet.types.FeatureSequence.add(FeatureSequence.java:131)
        at cc.mallet.pipe.TokenSequence2FeatureSequence.pipe(TokenSequence2FeatureSequence.java:44)
        at cc.mallet.pipe.Pipe$SimplePipeInstanceIterator.next(Pipe.java:294)
        at cc.mallet.pipe.Pipe$SimplePipeInstanceIterator.next(Pipe.java:282)
        at cc.mallet.types.InstanceList.addThruPipe(InstanceList.java:267)
        at cc.mallet.classify.tui.Csv2Vectors.main(Csv2Vectors.java:290)
```

Is there a workaround for such situations? Any help others can offer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1024GB?!?! you said 1G! shouldn´t it be 1024MB?

Comment: Yes @eduyayo, the system has 1TB of memory, and while I should only need a few GB, I  cranked the memory to 1024GB to see if doing so would resolve the problem, but no luck. It seems incredible to me too...

Comment: process limit will be fix by the system. In windows is not probably higher than 1.2 G... donno what system u´ve got but should check the proccess size limit

Comment: yes yes ulimit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651234/linux-process-memory-limit

Comment: I don't know Mallet but could you use Streams or some map/reduce instead of loading 1Tb in memory?

Comment: Keep in mind that the OS has to hold the entire Java process, which includes Java, any native libraries it, or you, require, plus the PermGen/Metaspace and the heap. There are going to be hard limits which you cannot exceed, and soft limits which you can, as discussed in these comments.

Comment: I run `sh -c "ulimit -n"` and get 65536.  I'm only trying to load 1GB into memory, using 1TB memory limit, but am getting a memory error. (The system has 3TB RAM.)

Answer (score 4):

If you are on Linux or OS X, I think you might be altering the wrong variable. The one you are changing is found in bin/mallet.bat, but you want to change the one in the executable at bin/mallet (i.e. without the *.bat* file extension):

```
MEMORY=1g
```

This is also described under "Issues with Big Data" in this Mallet tutorial:

http://programminghistorian.org/lessons/topic-modeling-and-mallet

Comment: sed -i.bak 's/MEMORY=1g/MEMORY=4g/' <pathtomallet>/bin/mallet  can be used to change this setting inplace if you are using a script to do this